# c++ boost format float - how to specify that I do not want . and following zeros

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point, formatting, boost-format

I would like to use `boost::format` to convert a float number to string.
These are several examples for the expected results:

```
0.5     -> "0.5"
0       -> "0"
1.00001 -> "1"
3.66    -> "3.7"
```

I am using currently

```
boost::format("%1$.1f")
```

it works mostly, but the result of `0` is `"0.0"` and `1.00001` is `"1.0"` when I want `"0"` and `"1"` instead.

What do I need to change to get rid of the pointless `.0`?

Comment: This will break the other cases where the precision must be 1

Answer (score 3):

Use a conditional to choose between two formats.

```
boost::format(abs(x-floor(x+0.05)) < 0.1 ? "%1$.0f" : "%1$.1f")
```

Comment: This will do it ... or ... trim right if zero, then trim right if dot.

I am surprised there is no way to specify this in the formatting expression itself

Comment: But in this case, 0.95 will be printed 1 instead of 0.9, though it is exactly 0.9499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875

Comment: @aka.nice, that's the reality of working with floating point - nothing will ever be exact, so there will always be corner cases. You can do the simple and obvious convert to string and strip off the trailing `.0` and then you can live with whatever rounding is built into your version of the standard library.

Comment: @MarkRansom I just wanted to remind that carefully written printf/scanf arrange to round correctly. So this function is a level of quality below printf. I guess it would be rejected for inclusion in boost for example. Sure, this small rounding error probably doesn't matter for a majority of applications, so this answer is not bad. It has the advantage of simplicity.